# How calculate the week if there are 5 weeks in one month?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

i have problem to calculate the week where the data just display four week. How calculate if there are five week?. i don't know how to do.
Anybody know about this?.:(

Comment: A bit more context wold be helpful

Comment: @AndrewCooper: Not context, but effort...

Comment: Your question is very unclear, but similar ones have been asked [numerous times](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+week+number) before on this site. One common answer is not to calculate anything, but to use a [calendar table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459260/calendar-table-week-number-of-month).

Answer (score 0):

select count(datepart(dw,datecoln)) as col1
from YourTable
group by datepart(dw,datecoln)
having month(datecoln)=@inputMonth

if you get and  any record with the value 5 in col1..

Answer (score 0):

Ideally we will not have 5 weeks in a month.

Comment: but that does not mean its 5 weeks in that month.

Answer (score -1):

Here the logic.

Calculate week number of given date

find first day of the month and also find its week number (**say start**)

find last day of month and also find its week number (**say end**)

**number off week in current date = end-start**

```
DECLARE @GivenDate datetime
DECLARE @start BIGINT
DECLARE @end BIGINT
SET @givendate=getdate()--You can supply your date

SET @start =  (SELECT DATEPART(wk,(SELECT DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,@GivenDate),0))))
SET @end =  (SELECT DATEPART(wk,(SELECT DATEADD(ms,- 3,DATEADD(mm,0,DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm,0,@GivenDate)+1,0))))))

SELECT (@end-@start)+1 AS NoOfWeeks
```

[Refer this to find week number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

[Or Refer this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928038/tsql-calculate-week-number-of-the-month)

Comment: This result is always 4 irrespective of any of the months..!! So I guess its not the perfect solution

Comment: that was a problem in substation, i corrected it. please check it

Comment: For september 2012 month its giving 6 weeks..!! thats not correct

Comment: Refer the calendar.
September 1st  35nd week

September 31 is 40th week

So the No week should be 6.

Comment: The way u are calculating the week number is not correct.In a week you have 7days and based on that you need to calculate.

Comment: Week number is the return value of sql function (DATEPART)
k,i will check.