# How to get week number of the month from the date in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

In SQL Statement in microsoft sql server, there is a built-in function to get week number but it is the week of the year.

```
Select DatePart(week, '2012/11/30') // **returns 48**
```

The returned value **48** is the week number of the year.

Instead of **48**, I want to get **1, 2, 3 or 4** (week number of the month). I think the week number of the month can be achieved by modules with Month Number of this week. For e.g.

```
Select DATEPART(week, '2012/11/30')%MONTH('2012/11/30')
```

But I want to know is there other built-in functions to get WeekNumber of the month in MS SQL SERVER.

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928038/tsql-calculate-week-number-of-the-month

while your solution is the one that looks most elegant to me. +1 for that

Comment: @nawfal the solution posted in the question is not even close to working

Comment: how do you define weeknumber ? Which day of the week start the week (sunday or monday). Do you want half weeks to be contained in 2 different months, do you want to handle it like iso_week or only whole weeks?

Comment: I confessed that the answer in this question is wrong. I will post the correct answer after I finish solving.

Comment: Sorry for necro. I needed something very similar, but all results I found are like @t-clausen.dk 's answer. My interpretation of the question above is that Jan 1 - Jan 7 would be week 1, Jan 8-14 week 2, etc. That's what I needed, and I came up with this: select (datepart(day, @date)  - 1) / 7 % 7 + 1

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Here are 2 different ways, both are assuming the week starts on monday

If you want weeks to be whole, so they belong to the month in which they start:
So saturday 2012-09-01 and sunday 2012-09-02 is week 4 and monday 2012-09-03 is week 1 use this:

```
DECLARE @date date = '2012-09-01'
SELECT (day(datediff(d,0,@date)/7*7)-1)/7+1
```

If your weeks cut on monthchange so saturday 2012-09-01 and sunday 2012-09-02 is week 1 and monday 2012-09-03 is week 2 use this:

```
DECLARE @date date = '2012-09-01'
SELECT 
  datediff(ww,datediff(d,0,dateadd(m,datediff(m,7,@date),0)
    )/7*7,dateadd(d,-1,@date))+1
```

I received an email from Gerald. He pointed out a flaw in the second method. This should be fixed now

I received an email from Ben Wilkins. He pointed out a flaw in the first method. This should be fixed now

Comment: didn't want to dv as I'd already upvoted - your 2nd solution returns week 6 for 31-mar-2014. this `select  datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, @date), 0)), 0), @date)` returns 5 which is correct.

Comment: although I am using SET DATEFIRST = 1

Comment: @bhs your datefirst should not affect this result at all. This result seems correct to me. There are 6 different weeks in march 2014

Comment: @t-clause.dk yes - you're right - apologies. In the report I am writing the sql for though they want it both ways - the week of the month but for yesterday to appear in week 5 :-). I think I'm going to 'persuade' them that dated weeks looks much better ;-)

Comment: @t-clausen.dk There is a (@date - 1) in the second "formula" that causes a conversion error. It should be replaced with just "@date" if I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: @TonyFiorentini you have probably declared your column as date instead of datetime, that would cause a conversion error

Comment: @t-clausen.dk When the first function is run for '2015-Nov-01', the function returns 4. When by your description it should return 6.

Comment: @BDays it returns 4 like intended according to the explanation

Comment: So the function is flawed according to the explanation? How can '1-Nov-2015' be week 4 and the '30-Nov-2015' week5? Then you would have two sundays in that month reporting week4

Comment: no it isn't flawed. It starts at the first whole week of the month. Week 1 starts at 2015-10-05(monday) It ends at the last week with a at least one day in the same month. Making sunday 2015-11-01 the last day in 4th week in october. As explained in the answer. Maybe you are confused by the text for the second answer

Answer (score 13):

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME
SET @DATE = '2013-08-04'

SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, @DATE)  -
    DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MM, DATEDIFF(MM,0,@DATE), 0))+ 1 AS WEEK_OF_MONTH
```

Comment: This does not work for second Sunday, it show in 3rd week.

Comment: This works correctly in such that if a month end and begins mid week the proper week number is returned. ie.  2018-07-31 ends on a Tuesday, week 5.  2018-08-01 begins on a Wednesday, week 1.

Answer (score 9):

No built-in function. It depends what you mean by week of month.  You might mean whether it's in the first 7 days (week 1), the second 7 days (week 2), etc.  In that case it would just be

`(DATEPART(day,@Date)-1)/7 + 1`

If you want to use the same week numbering as is used with DATEPART(week,), you could use the difference between the week numbers of the first of the month and the date in question (+1):

`(DATEPART(week,@Date)- DATEPART(week,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @Date), 0))) + 1`

Or, you might need something else, depending on what you mean by the week number.

Comment: you should not use Datepart, it is not a reliable method. It relies of the setting for *DATEFIRST*. The result will be different on different SQL servers

Answer (score 7):

Just look at the date and see what range it falls in.

Range 1-7 is the 1st week, Range 8-14 is the 2nd week, etc.

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,yourdate) < 8 THEN '1' 
  ELSE CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,yourdate) < 15 then '2' 
    ELSE CASE WHEN  DATEPART(day,yourdate) < 22 then '3' 
      ELSE CASE WHEN  DATEPART(day,yourdate) < 29 then '4'     
        ELSE '5'
      END
    END
  END
END
```

Comment: this rely on a specific setting for DATEFIRST. It will not work on all systems

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the second solution, less code:

```
declare @date datetime = '2014-03-31'
SELECT DATEDIFF(week,0,@date) - (DATEDIFF(week,0,DATEADD(dd, -DAY(@date)+1, @date))-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check this out... its working fine.

```
declare @date as datetime = '2014-03-10'
select DATEPART(week,@date) - DATEPART(week,cast(cast(year(@date) as varchar(4))+'-' + cast(month(@date) as varchar(2)) + '-01' as datetime))+1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WeekMonth = CASE WHEN (DATEPART(day,TestDate) - datepart(dw,TestDate))>= 22 THEN '5' 
                 WHEN (DATEPART(day,TestDate) - datepart(dw,TestDate))>= 15 THEN '4' 
                 WHEN (DATEPART(day,TestDate) - datepart(dw,TestDate))>= 8 THEN '3'
                 WHEN (DATEPART(day,TestDate) - datepart(dw,TestDate))>= 1 THEN '2' 
                 ELSE '1'
             END
```

Comment: Seems that `datepart(dw,TestDate)` returns by default [1 for Sunday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877124/sql-datepartdw-date-need-monday-1-and-sunday-7), so it can move sundays one week later without proper configuration. Otherwise +1 for considering that not all months start with monday

Answer (score 1):

There is no inbuilt function to get you the week number. I dont think dividing will help you anyway as the number of weeks in a month is not constant.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675168.aspx

I guess you can divide the number(48) by 4 and take the modules of the same and project that as the week number of that month, by adding one to the result.

Comment: Friend, thanks for your answer but it's wrong. For example, if week number of '2011/11/20' (YYYY/MM/DD) is divided by 4, the module "0" will be out. In addition, I confessed that my answer is not correct so that I used the term "I think".

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion for getting the first and last days of the week for a month:

```
-- Build a temp table with all the dates of the month 
drop table #tmp_datesforMonth 
go

declare @begDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime

set @begDate = '6/1/13'
set @endDate = '6/30/13';

WITH N(n) AS  
(   SELECT 0  
        UNION ALL 
    SELECT n+1 
    FROM N 
    WHERE n <= datepart(dd,@enddate)
)
SELECT      DATEADD(dd,n,@BegDate) as dDate 
into #tmp_datesforMonth
FROM        N
WHERE       MONTH(DATEADD(dd,n,@BegDate)) = MONTH(@BegDate)

--- pull results showing the weeks' dates and the week # for the month (not the week # for the current month) 

select  MIN(dDate) as BegOfWeek
, MAX(dDate) as EndOfWeek 
, datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dDate), 0)), 0), dDate) as WeekNumForMonth 
from #tmp_datesforMonth
group by datediff(week, dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dDate), 0)), 0), dDate) 
order by 3, 1
```

Answer (score 1):

A dirty but easy one liner using Dense_Rank function. Performance WILL suffer, but effective none the less.

```
DENSE_RANK()over(Partition by Month(yourdate),Year(yourdate) Order by Datepart(week,yourdate) asc) as Week
```

Answer (score 1):

```
floor((day(@DateValue)-1)/7)+1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go....

Im using the code below..

```
DATEPART(WK,@DATE_INSERT) - DATEPART(WK,DATEADD(DAY,1,DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,@DATE_INSERT),0)))) + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query that brings the week number on whatever the `startday` and `endday` of the week it may be.

```
SET DATEFIRST 2    

DECLARE @FROMDATE DATE='12-JAN-2015'
-- Get the first day of month
DECLARE @ALLDATE DATE=DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, @FROMDATE), 0)
DECLARE @FIRSTDATE DATE


;WITH  CTE as
(
     -- Get all dates in that month
     SELECT 1 RNO,CAST(@ALLDATE AS DATE) as DATES 
     UNION ALL
     SELECT RNO+1, DATEADD(DAY,1,DATES )
     FROM    CTE
     WHERE   DATES < DATEADD(MONTH,1,@ALLDATE)
)
-- Retrieves the first day of week, ie, if first day of week is Tuesday, it selects first Tuesday 
SELECT TOP 1 @FIRSTDATE =   DATES 
FROM    CTE 
WHERE DATEPART(W,DATES)=1

SELECT (DATEDIFF(DAY,@FIRSTDATE,@FROMDATE)/7)+1 WEEKNO
```

For more information I have answered for the below question. Can check that.

- [How do I find week number of a date according to DATEFIRST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700839/how-do-i-find-week-number-of-a-date-according-to-datefirst)

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Code:

```
declare @dt datetime='2018-03-15 05:16:00.000'
IF (Select (DatePart(DAY,@dt)%7))>0
  Select  (DatePart(DAY,@dt)/7) +1
ELSE
  Select  (DatePart(DAY,@dt)/7)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an inbuilt option to get the week number of the **year**

```
**select datepart(week,getdate())**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get week number by getting minimum week number of month and deduct it from week number. Suppose you have a table with dates

```
select
    emp_id, dt , datepart(wk,dt) - (select min(datepart(wk,dt))
from
    workdates ) + 1 from workdates
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
declare @dt datetime='2018-03-31 05:16:00.000'
IF (Select (DatePart(DAY,@dt)%7))>0
Select  (DatePart(DAY,@dt)/7) +1
ELSE
Select  (DatePart(DAY,@dt)/7)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @end_date datetime = '2019-02-28';
select datepart(week, @end_date) - datepart(week, convert(datetime, substring(convert(nvarchar, convert(datetime, @end_date), 127), 1, 8) + '01')) + 1 [Week of Month];
```

Comment: You should add some explanation.

Comment: More explanation would make it easier for the question asker to understand what you are trying to convey. I would suggest going back an adding additional detail as to why this is the right answer for the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tried and tested solution for this query in any situation - like if 1st of the month is on Friday , then also this will work -

```
select (DATEPART(wk,@date_given)-DATEPART(wk,dateadd(d,1-day(@date_given),@date_given)))+1
```

above are some solutions which will fail if the month's first date is on Friday , then 4th will be 2nd week of the month

Answer (score 0):

Logic here works as well 4.3 weeks in every month. Take that from the DATEPART(WEEK) on every month but January. Just another way of looking at things. This would also account for months where there is a 5th week

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(10)
SET @date = '7/27/2019'

SELECT CEILING(DATEPART(WEEK,@date)-((DATEPART(MONTH,@date)-1)*4.3333)) 'Week of Month'
```

Answer (score 0):

Below will only work if you have every week of the month represented in the select list. Else the rank function will not work, but it is a good solution.

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY MONTH(DATEFIELD) 
                          ORDER BY DATEPART(WEEK,DATEFIELD) ASC) AS WeekofMont
```

Comment: Thanks TT. the Edit looks a lot better!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
declare @date datetime = '20210928'

select convert(int,(((cast(datepart(day,@date) as decimal(4,2))/7)-(1.00/7.00))+1.00))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select datepart(week,@date)-datepart(week,dateadd(day,1,eomonth(dateadd(m,-1,@date))))+1
```

or

```
select datepart(week,@date)-datepart(week,dateadd(d,-datepart(d,@date)+1,@date))+1
```

steps:
1,get the first day of month
2,week of year of the date - week of year of the first day of the month
3,+1

2023-1-1 is sunday

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;
DECLARE @date date = '2023-1-02';
select datepart(week,@date)-datepart(week,dateadd(day,1,eomonth(dateadd(m,-1,@date))))+1
```

return 2

```
SET DATEFIRST 7;
DECLARE @date date = '2023-1-02';
select datepart(week,@date)-datepart(week,dateadd(day,1,eomonth(dateadd(m,-1,@date))))+1
```

return 1

Answer (score 0):

You can try below statement.

select datepart(week, getdate()) - datepart(week, DATEADD(ms,0,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,getdate()),0))) + 1

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

Code is below:

```
set datefirst 7
declare @dt datetime='29/04/2016 00:00:00'
select (day(@dt)+datepart(WEEKDAY,dateadd(d,-day(@dt),@dt+1)))/7
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select @DateCreated, DATEDIFF(WEEK, @DateCreated, GETDATE())
```