# PostgreSQL Crosstab generate_series of weeks for columns

Tags: postgresql, crosstab, generate-series

From a table of "time entries" I'm trying to create a report of weekly totals for each user.

Sample of the table:

```
+-----+---------+-------------------------+--------------+
| id  | user_id | start_time              | hours_worked |
+-----+---------+-------------------------+--------------+
| 997 | 6       | 2018-01-01 03:05:00 UTC | 1.0          |
| 996 | 6       | 2017-12-01 05:05:00 UTC | 1.0          |
| 998 | 6       | 2017-12-01 05:05:00 UTC | 1.5          |
| 999 | 20      | 2017-11-15 19:00:00 UTC | 1.0          |
| 995 | 6       | 2017-11-11 20:47:42 UTC | 0.04         |
+-----+---------+-------------------------+--------------+
```

Right now I can run the following and basically get what I need

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(time_entries.hours_worked),0) AS total, 
  time_entries.user_id, 
  week::date

--Using generate_series here to account for weeks with no time entries when
--doing the join

FROM generate_series( (DATE_TRUNC('week', '2017-11-01 00:00:00'::date)),
                      (DATE_TRUNC('week', '2017-12-31 23:59:59.999999'::date)),
                      interval '7 day') as week LEFT JOIN time_entries
ON DATE_TRUNC('week', time_entries.start_time) = week

GROUP BY week, time_entries.user_id
ORDER BY week
```

This will return

```
+-------+---------+------------+
| total | user_id | week       |
+-------+---------+------------+
| 14.08 | 5       | 2017-10-30 |
| 21.92 | 6       | 2017-10-30 |
| 10.92 | 7       | 2017-10-30 |
| 14.26 | 8       | 2017-10-30 |
| 14.78 | 10      | 2017-10-30 |
| 14.08 | 13      | 2017-10-30 |
| 15.83 | 15      | 2017-10-30 |
| 8.75  | 5       | 2017-11-06 |
| 10.53 | 6       | 2017-11-06 |
| 13.73 | 7       | 2017-11-06 |
| 14.26 | 8       | 2017-11-06 |
| 19.45 | 10      | 2017-11-06 |
| 15.95 | 13      | 2017-11-06 |
| 14.16 | 15      | 2017-11-06 |
| 1.00  | 20      | 2017-11-13 |
| 0     |         | 2017-11-20 |
| 2.50  | 6       | 2017-11-27 |
| 0     |         | 2017-12-04 |
| 0     |         | 2017-12-11 |
| 0     |         | 2017-12-18 |
| 0     |         | 2017-12-25 |
+-------+---------+------------+
```

However, this is difficult to parse particularly when there's no data for a week.  What I would like is a pivot or crosstab table where the weeks are the columns and the rows are the users.  And to include nulls from each (for instance if a user had no entries in that week or week without entries from any user).

Something like this

```
+---------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| user_id | 2017-10-30    | 2017-11-06   | 2017-11-13   |
+---------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
| 6       | 4.0           | 1.0          | 0            |
| 7       | 4.0           | 1.0          | 0            |
| 8       | 4.0           | 0            | 0            |
| 9       | 0             | 1.0          | 0            |
| 10      | 4.0           | 0.04         | 0            |
+---------+---------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I've been looking around online and it seems that "dynamically" generating a list of columns for crosstab is [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12879672/dynamically-generate-columns-for-crosstab-in-postgresql).  I'd rather not hard code them, which seems weird to do anyway for dates.  Or use something like this [case with week number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19709395/sql-postgres-aggregation-pivot-of-data-by-weeks-with-totals).

Should I look for another solution besides crosstab?  If I could get the series of weeks for each user including all nulls I think that would be good enough.  It just seems that right now my join strategy isn't returning that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use a Date Dimension table and use that table as the basis for the query. I find it far easier to use tabular data for these types of calculations as it leads to SQL that's easier to read and maintain. There's a great article on creating a Date Dimension table in PostgreSQL at https://medium.com/@duffn/creating-a-date-dimension-table-in-postgresql-af3f8e2941ac, though you could get away with a much simpler version of this table.

Ultimately what you would do is use the Date table as the base for the `SELECT cols FROM table` section and then join against that, or probably use Common Table Expressions, to create the calculations.

I'll write up a solution to that if you would like demonstrating how you could create such a query.