# SQL DATEPART(dw,date) need monday = 1 and sunday = 7

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Query where I get the **WeekDay** of a date but by default:

- Sunday = 1
- Moday = 2
- etc.

The function is:

```
DATEPART(dw,ads.date) as weekday
```

I need the result so:

- Sunday = 7
- Monday = 1
- etc.

Is there any shortcut to do this? Or I will have to do a `CASE statement`?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use a formula like:

```
(weekday + 5) % 7 + 1
```

If you decide to use this, it would be worth running through some examples to convince yourself that it actually does what you want.

**addition**:
for not to be affected by the DATEFIRST variable (it could be set to any value between 1 and 7) the real formula is :

```
(weekday  + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1
```

Comment: I tried this: (DATEPART(dw,ads.date)+5) mod 7 + 1 as weekday but I get an error on the mod. Maybe the order is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, SQL Server uses different syntax. I've fixed my answer to use `%` instead of `mod`.

Comment: While this works for OP I think that it might break if the language of the user is changed.

Answer (score 81):

This will do it.

```
SET DATEFIRST 1;

-- YOUR QUERY
```

Examples

```
-- Sunday is first day of week
set datefirst 7; 
select DATEPART(dw,getdate()) as weekday


-- Monday is first day of week
set datefirst 1;
select DATEPART(dw,getdate()) as weekday
```

Comment: @RobForrest - I don't like either, to be honest. One assumes a particular datefirst setting, the other assumes you *can* set it. But if you're authoring a View or UDF in an environment where different users have different defaults, neither is possible.

Comment: I used this answer in June 2018, now came here to tell that @Damien_The_Unbeliever was right.

Comment: His comment was added few months later and I did not count for that scenario in the heat of solving problem at hand.

Answer (score 20):

You can tell SQL Server to use Monday as the start of the week using [DATEFIRST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms181598.aspx) like this:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
```

Answer (score 11):

I would suggest that you just write the case statement yourself using `datename()`:

```
select (case datename(dw, aws.date)
             when 'Monday' then 1
             when 'Tuesday' then 2
             when 'Wednesday' then 3
             when 'Thursday' then 4
             when 'Friday' then 5
             when 'Saturday' then 6
             when 'Sunday' then 7
        end)
```

At least, this won't change if someone changes the parameter on the day of the week when weeks begin.  On the other hand, it is susceptible to the language chosen for SQL Server.

Comment: You replaced one non-deterministic function with another non-deterministic function. This gives nothing since you simply replaced the dependency on the stetting of SET DATEFIRST with the dependency in the setting of the SET LANGUAGE. This function uses hard coded names in English so it will not work in other languages.

Comment: Please never do this. Not only is a string comparison incredibly inefficient and unnecessary, it assumes that it's running on an English language server; it will fail if the script is migrated to a different language, if the native language is changed on the server, or even if the language is not English on the connection. It's a cultural universality time-bomb - a potentially critical bug waiting to manifest itself.

Answer (score 7):

You can use this formula regardless of `DATEFIRST` setting :

```
((DatePart(WEEKDAY, getdate()) + @@DATEFIRST + 6 - [first day that you need] ) % 7) + 1;
```

for `monday = 1`

```
((DatePart(WEEKDAY, getdate()) + @@DATEFIRST + 6 - 1 ) % 7) + 1;
```

and for `sunday = 1`

```
((DatePart(WEEKDAY, getdate()) + @@DATEFIRST + 6 - 7 ) % 7) + 1;
```

and for `friday = 1`

```
((DatePart(WEEKDAY, getdate()) + @@DATEFIRST + 6 - 5 ) % 7) + 1;
```

Comment: Very useful approach.

Answer (score 2):

Simply subtract one day from your ads.date field and use in DATEPART function:

```
DATEPART(dw,DATEADD(day,-1,ads.date)) as weekday
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is the following:

```
ISNULL(NULLIF(DATEPART(dw,DateField)-1,0),7)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by the account the SQL Server service is run under. For example;

If the SQL Server Service is run under DOMAIN\MyUserAccount then this will need to be a login and set with the relevant Language.

If this account isn't set then SQL Server will default to the sa account and the Language that runs under.

I found that our sa account was set to English which had Monday as DW = 2. The DOMAIN\MyUserAccount Account was setup and changed to British English and DW for Monday was being returned as 1.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think this could work:

```
  select
    case when datepart(dw,[Date]) = 1 then 7 else DATEPART(DW,[Date])-1 end as WeekDay
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.FnDAYSADDNOWK(
          @addDate AS DATE, 
          @numDays AS INT
       ) RETURNS DATETIME AS

    BEGIN
    WHILE @numDays > 0 BEGIN
        SET @addDate = DATEADD(day, 1, @addDate)    
        IF DATENAME(DW, @addDate) <> 'sunday' BEGIN
            SET @numDays = @numDays - 1 
        END
    END

    RETURN CAST(@addDate AS DATETIME)
END
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question; providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the DATEFIRST settings is the only way, but it's not possible to make a SET statement in a scalar/table valued function. Therefore, it becomes very error-prone to the colleagues following your code. (become a trap to the others)

In fact, SQL server datepart function should be improved to accept this as parameter instead.

At the meantime, it looks like using the English Name of the week is the safest choice.

Answer (score 0):

`-- Monday is first day of week set datefirst 1; select DATEPART(dw,getdate()) as weekday`

SQLChao answer still works prefectly well

Answer (score -1):

You would need to set DATEFIRST. Take a look at this article. I believe this should help.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql

Comment: This solution has already been mentioned several times, several years ago.

Answer (score -4):

I think

```
DATEPART(dw,ads.date - 1) as weekday
```

would work.