# How do I alias particular values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I will present a question about 'aliasing' values from a column. I will use days of the week as an intuitive example to get my question across, but I am ***not*** asking for datetime conversions.

Suppose I have the following SQL script:

```
SELECT DaysOfWeek 
FROM [databasename].[dbo].[tablename]
```

Now, the column `DaysOfWeek` will return string values of the days' names, i.e. "Monday," "Tuesday," and so forth.

What if I wanted the query to return the integer 1 for 'Monday', 2 for 'Tuesday', and so forth? I would want to assign a particular value to each of the week's days in the `SELECT` statement, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

I'm relatively new to SQL, so I just thought I'd ask for an intuitive method to perform such a task.

**Edited to add:** I'm only using days of the week and their respective integer representation as an easy example; my task does not involve days of the week, but rather employee code numbers and corresponding titles.

Comment: The normal way is to store the integer values in the first place. Do you really only have a string in your table? Can you fix that?

Comment: Is DaysOfWeek a column in the table or is it a stored function? It can't be a variable.

Comment: Please see my edit- thanks. @Anand, I meant to say "column." I'll change that now.

Comment: Sounds to me like you need to read about lookup tables and normalization. Lookup tables are the life blood of most relational databases and understanding them is crucial to the success of your system. They are as basic and common as a select statement.

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL DATEPART(dw,date) need monday = 1 and sunday = 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877124/sql-datepartdw-date-need-monday-1-and-sunday-7)

Comment: @GarrettVlieger No, it isn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using `case`:

```
SELECT (CASE DaysOfWeek 
             WHEN 'Monday' THEN 1
             WHEN 'Tuesday' THEN 2
             . . .
        END)
```

Under most circumstances, it is unnecessary to store the day of the week like this.  You can readily use a function, `datepart()` or `datename()`, to extract the day of the week from a date/time value.

If the column is in a table, and not part of a date, then you might want to include the above logic as a computed column:

```
alter table t add DayOfWeekNumber as (case DaysOfWeek when 'Monday' then 1 . . .);
```

Comment: `case` is the operative term I was looking for. I understand the benefits of using a reference table, but for intellectual curiosity's sake, I wanted to know how one could use a snippet of code within the script to accomplish the same thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to define your own corresponding value for another value, the best way is to use a table, and join that table.

For example:

```
create table dbo.EmployeeTitle (
    id int not null identity(1,1) primary key
  , title varchar(32)
  );

create table dbo.Employee (
    id int not null identity(1,1) primary key
  , name nvarchar(128)
  , title_id int references dbo.EmployeeTitle(id)
  );

insert into dbo.EmployeeTitle values ('Big boss');
insert into dbo.Employee values ('daOnlyBG',1);

select e.*, et.title
from dbo.Employee e
  inner join dbo.EmployeeTitle et
    on e.title_id = et.id
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/FXIM78632

returns:

```
+----+----------+----------+----------+
| id |   name   | title_id |  title   |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
|  1 | daOnlyBG |        1 | Big boss |
+----+----------+----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Use CASE, [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ar/library/ms181765.aspx) you have the definition and one example :

```
select
    CASE 
          WHEN(DaysOfWeek="Monday") THEN 1
          WHEN(DaysOfWeek="Thusday") THEN 2
          ....
    ELSE  -1 
from table
```

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is to have a table variable or CTE; create your lookup as rows and join to it. Something like this:

```
with cte as (
  select 1 as emp_code, 'value1' as emp_title
  union
  select 2 as emp_code, 'value2' as emp_title
  union
  select 3 as emp_code, 'value3' as emp_title
)

select cte.emp_code, tableName.*
from tableName
inner join cte
on cte.emp_title = tableName.some_column
```