# I need previous Monday's date, unless today is a Monday, then use today's date

Tags: sql, sql-server

This seems to be a common issue, which I cannot seem to find the answer for, so hoping for some new insight please.

I need to find the previous Monday's date, unless the date passed to the statement is itself a Monday, then I need to use that date.

I have tried the following

```
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,StartDate), 0)
```

This returns the correct date, unless it is a Sunday, then it returns the next Monday instead of the last Monday.

```
DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk,0,StartDate), -1)
```

This returns Sunday instead of Monday.

```
DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DATEPART(WEEKDAY, StartDate), StartDate)
```

This also returns Sunday.

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL DATEPART(dw,date) need monday = 1 and sunday = 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877124/sql-datepartdw-date-need-monday-1-and-sunday-7) You can then easily add the output of the solution to the current date to get Monday's date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24877143/2029983) as inspiration, one method would be to use their expression to get an unambiguous day number, with Monday as `0` and Sunday as `6`, then then *subtract* that day number from the current date:

```sql
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE())  + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7,CONVERT(date,GETDATE()))
```

Alternatively, on the latest version of the data engine, you can use `DATE_BUCKET`. Unlike `DATEPART`, `DATE_BUCKET` isn't affected by the language settings for things like when a week starts. When its 4th parameter is omitted, it always uses `1900-01-01` as it's start date, which conveniently (here) is a Monday. This means that with that parameter omitted, asking for the date the "week bucket" started will return a Monday as well.

```sql
SELECT DATE_BUCKET(WEEK,1,GETDATE());
```

Also inspired by [El.MENSI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9377539/el-mensi)'s now [deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75162514/2029983), who attempted to use `DATE_TRUNC` (possibly MySQL syntax), though you can't use `WEEK` for the truncation, you could use `ISO_WEEK`, which always starts on a Monday. This too, however, is only supported on the latest version of the data engine:

```sql
SELECT DATE_TRUNC(ISO_WEEK, GETDATE());
```

Comment: Minor request for improvement - explicitly calling out what version of SQL `DATE_BUCKET` is available. Imagine this answer being read in 10 years time and SQL 2032 is out. `DATE_BUCKET` will have been available in several versions and so the person hoping to implement your solution has a much better chance of having it available.

Comment: I said data engine for a reason, @BenThul . It isn't just SQL Server 2022+ that supports `DATE_BUCKET`, it's also supported in Azure SQL Database and Managed instances. Obviously the "latest version [of the data engine]" would be "at time of writing."

Comment: Thank you for the reply and comments. The first answer worked perfectly, thank you :). Unfortunately I am using 2018 version so the DATE_BUCKET option isn't available to me. I will note it down for when I am using a later version.

Comment: *"Unfortunately I am using 2018 version"* There is no SQL Server 2018 @Countrygirl ; there were releases in 2017 and  2019, but not in 2018.