# If current date is a certain day of the week, pull results from a different day

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, case

I'm working on a SQL query that pulls results for everyone who had appointments at a clinic on a given day. I run this query daily for all appointments that took place the previous business day. The query is pretty basic:

```
SELECT
[a bunch of demographic and appointment-related fields]

FROM Demographics d JOIN ApptInfo ai ON d.PatientID = ai.PatientID

WHERE (ai.ApptDate >= DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,1,GETDATE()),0)
      AND ai.ApptDate < DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0))
```

This works great so far, unless I'm running the query on a Monday. In that case, I need to be able to pull all the results from the previous Friday ***and*** Saturday, since the clinic is also open for half days on Saturdays. Obviously I can't do that by only looking at the previous day, since that would be a Sunday.

I can see the logic pretty clearly in my head for what I want to do, but I'm unsure how exactly to set it up. It needs to be something along these lines:

```
WHERE
    (CASE
        WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 'Monday' THEN [pull results where ApptDate is 3 days ago OR 2 days ago]
        ELSE [the same code shown above that pulls the previous day]
     END)
```

Am I on the right track? The alternative of course would be to just manually plug in whatever dates I'm trying to look at, but it would be awesome to be able to run this query daily and have it be completely automated, even on Mondays.

Comment: so which dates exactly 24 and 25, or 24th till 27th

Comment: @nbk so for example if I'm running the query on a Monday today (the 27th) I need to be able to see Friday/24th and Saturday/25th. Technically I suppose I could include Sunday/26th since there would simply be no results from that day, but I need to not actually capture any results from the 27th until the following day, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, parametrising the dates would likely be *better* for readability. You can still do it in the same batch though.

I use a somewhat "round about" way (see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24877143/2029983) by [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893/greg-hewgill)) to check what weekday it is because I want to ensure that the same result is given *regardless* of the language/`DATEFIRST` setting:

```sql
DECLARE @DateFrom date = CASE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, -3,GETDATE()) ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -1,GETDATE()) END,
        @Dateto date = GETDATE(); --Considering there is no data on a Sunday, this is "fine"

--SELECT @DateFrom, @Dateto

SELECT [a bunch of demographic and appointment-related fields]
FROM dbo.Demographics D
     JOIN dbo.ApptInfo AI ON D.PatientID = AI.PatientID
WHERE AI.ApptDate >= @DateFrom
  AND AI.ApptDate < @Dateto;
```

If you "must" do it without variables, then it would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT [a bunch of demographic and appointment-related fields]
FROM dbo.Demographics D
     JOIN dbo.ApptInfo AI ON D.PatientID = AI.PatientID
WHERE AI.ApptDate >= CONVERT(date,CASE (DATEPART(WEEKDAY,GETDATE()) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 WHEN 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY, -3,GETDATE())
                                                                                                ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -1,GETDATE())
                                  END)
  AND AI.ApptDate < CONVERT(date,GETDATE());
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use a case for bboth dates

```
SELECT
*

FROM Demographics d JOIN ApptInfo ai ON d.PatientID = ai.PatientID

WHERE (ai.ApptDate > CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 'Monday' THEN   DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,4,GETDATE()),0)
  ELSE DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,1,GETDATE()),0) END 
      AND ai.ApptDate < CASE WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 'Monday' THEN 
  DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,1,GETDATE()),0) ELSE DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,0,GETDATE()),0) END )
```

Comment: This works great too, thanks! The only thing is when I ran this code exactly as shown, with  the `DATEADD(dd,DATEDIFF(dd,3,GETDATE()),0)` segment, it only pulled results from Saturday. Changing that 3 to a 4 allowed Friday results to be included as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by defining today at midnight:

```
DECLARE @today datetime = CAST(getdate() AS date);
```

Some things that we know about datetimes.  First, a datetime is stored as an integer offset - which means the integer 0 is 1900-01-01.  Second, we also know that this date is a Monday so now we can check for the day of the week simply using modulo:

```
CAST(getdate() AS int) % 7
```

Regardless of DATEFIRST setting - the above will always return a 0 for Monday, 1 for Tuesday, 2 for Wednesday, etc.

With that - the formula is this:

```
WHERE ai.ApptDate >= DATEADD(day, -iif(cast(getdate() As int) % 7 = 0, 4, 1), @today)
  AND ai.ApptDate  < @today
```

This doesn't work for the newer data types (datetime2, datetimeoffset) because those are not stored as integers and cannot be cast/converted directly to an integer.  However, we can get the integer value using:

```
DATEDIFF(day, '0001-01-01', sysdatetime())
```

So the modulo of that value will be the same as the modulo of the integer value of a datetime.  To avoid having different formulas:

```
WHERE ai.ApptDate >= DATEADD(day, -iif(DATEDIFF(day, '0001-01-01', sysdatetime()) % 7 = 0, 4, 1), @today)
  AND ai.ApptDate  < @today
```