# SQL Week of Month without DATEFIRST

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working with dates so I have created a function that generates a SQL Table Calendar which returns Day, Month, WeekOfMonth, WeekOfYear and so on.
Right now, for the Day of Month field I am using the following function:

```
    -- [WkNo]=Week number                                
    [WkNo]      = DATEPART(week,dt.DT),
```

But the problem is that when I run this on a SQL installed with Language = US English, the week setting is wrong cause the week starts from Sunday.
I need to set the week starting from Monday, is it possible without the use of DATEPART?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. See this answer from @t-clausen.dk: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13119920/2203084

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:** based on asker's comment that he cannot use the `DATEFIRST` approach I am updating answer.

**Note:**

This answer is generic in nature.

If instead of Monday you want the week to start from Tuesday, you can change the `dateadd(dd,-1,dt.DT)` to `dateadd(dd,-2,dt.DT)` and for Wednesday to `dateadd(dd,-3,dt.DT)`.

Basically the formula becomes `dateadd(dd,-n,dt.DT)` for value of **n** ranging over **1**(Monday) to **6** (Saturday).

```
SELECT  [WkNo]=
 ISNULL(DATEPART(week,
                      case 
                         when Year(dt.DT)>YEAR(dateadd(dd,-1,dt.DT)) 
                         then null  
                         else dateadd(dd,-1,dt.DT) 
                      end
                 ),1)
```

See working fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/10a80/14

**Old Answer:**
See MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

> When datepart is week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw), the return value
>   depends on the value that is set by using SET DATEFIRST. January 1 of
>   any year defines the starting number for the week datepart, for
>   example: DATEPART (wk, 'Jan 1, xxxx') = 1, where xxxx is any year.

```
    SET DATEFIRST 1
 -- [WkNo]=Week number                                
    [WkNo]      = DATEPART(week,dt.DT),
```

Comment: I cannot use DATEFIRST, so I cannot accept your solution

Comment: @Raffaeu Why can't you use Datefirst?

Comment: Because I use a VIEW and a FUNCTION and I cannot use SET DATEFIRST 1 within their call and I cannot have sequential calls because the VIEW is used by a Report Engine. So within the VIEW or FUNCTION I should set DATEFIRST, which is not possible on SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

try

```
SET DATEFIRST {1,2,3,4,5,6,7(default, U.S. English)}
```

for your Query:

```
set datefirst 1
select [WkNo]= DATEPART(week,dt.DT)
```

See [Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx)

Comment: I cannot use DATEFIRST, so I cannot accept your solution