# How to get week numbers for whole year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My scenario: I have `SalesDate` (eg: 2007-01-01 to 2016-01-01) filed like this up to `todate` and have daily date. Now I have to find this `salesdate` belong to which week.

**Condition**

Start day of week is `Sunday`. Based on year, if new year starts week count start as 1.

Comment: can u pl refer this link which may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116222/how-to-get-week-number-of-the-month-from-the-date-in-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like below,

```
DECLARE @SalesDate DATETIME = '2007-01-01'
SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, @SalesDate), 0)), 0), @SalesDate - 1) + 1 WeekD, @SalesDate SalesDate
```

OR

```
DECLARE @SalesDate DATETIME = '2007-01-01'
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,@SalesDate) WeekNumber, @SalesDate SalesDate
```

Comment: Thanks All i Got it & Solve this issue.