# sql code to get week number for FiscalYear

Tags: sql-server

Need sql code to get week number for FiscalYear –
Date table ranges from 1975 to 2024

Already have weekno (WeekOfYear) for CalendarYear
 -week count start from 1st of April and end on 31st march
 -Week start from Sunday to Saturday
 -On Fiscalyear end, week also ended

eg. 
1st apr 2016 -Week 1
2nd apr 2016 - week 1
3rd apr 2016 to 9th apr 2016 -week 2
10th apr 2016 to 16th apr 2016 -week 3 ... and so on

Comment: I'd highly recommend creating a date table that will hold this information. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get week number of the month from the date in sql server 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116222/how-to-get-week-number-of-the-month-from-the-date-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: @ mister - it isn't a duplicate of week number because that other question does not seem to mention the fiscal  year, and the example given nowhere near fits in with the examples her - fiscal week 48 is not in November

Answer (score 0):

Writing a query to do this, seems to me very complicated. I advise you to do it either by using a table (Choice1) or by creating an EXCEL file (Choice2).

**Choice1**: Create a WeekCalendarForFiscalYear table with 4 fields [DateOfToday, weekNumber, FiscalYear].

- In DateOfToday, you put the date of the day.
- In WeekNumber, you put the number of the fiscal week.
- In FiscalYear, you are in the fiscal year (2016, 2017, 2018, etc.).

  You have to think about indexing these fields.

  ***/!\*** : You can also create your table like this: WeekCalendarForFiscalYear with 4 fields [WeekNumber, FiscalYear, StartDate, EndDate]. StartDate would correspond to the beginning of the fiscal week and EndDate at the end of the fiscal week.

**Choix2**: You create an EXCEL file in which you enter the data either as in *Choix1*, or as it suits you.

- The file must be physically on the server of the database.
- You access the file via OPENROWSET. You will find on the web a wide
  range of sites that will help you to use OPENROWSET well.

Hope this can help.

Answer (score 0):

assuming DATEFIRST is 7, I got this function - actually you can default datefirst = 7 for the lifetime of your query only - this seems to work according to by 1980 calendar

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date, ,>
-- Description: <Description, ,>
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION FiscalYearMonth
(
    @DAT datetime

)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @TAXY as int;
    DECLARE @R as int;

    SET @TAXY = YEAR(dateadd(month,-3,@dat));
    DECLARE @TDAT as  varchar(8) 

    SET @TDAT = CAST(@TAXY AS varchar(4)) + '0401';

    SELECT @R = datediff(day,  DATEADD(day , (8 - DATEPART(DW,@TDAT)) % 7,@TDAT), dateadd(day,14,@DAT)) / 7;

    RETURN @R;

END
GO
```

e.g.

```
 SET datefirst   7;
select dbo.FiscalYearMonth('19800413')
```