# get the WEEK of a date by using mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

How can I get the week number of a date by using mysqli for each entry?

Given I have `table1` containing a `date` column with the following two entries:

```
2018-03-14
2018-05-14
```

I wish to see the week numbers of the above two entries. My main problem is that I do not know how to process the result of my query.

---

```php
$sql = 'SELECT WEEK(date) FROM table1 WHERE YEAR(beginn) = "2018"';

$db_erg = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

while ($row = $db_erg->fetch_array())
{
  echo $row[0]; // or $row['week'] if you used AS week
}
```

Comment: [Did you check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116222/how-to-get-week-number-of-the-month-from-the-date-in-sql-server-2008) ?

Comment: Your query should work. Please add your expected result and the current result.

Comment: Yes, I think that the jquery is correct, too but I can I display it? echo..?

Comment: If you think the query is correct, what is the problem exactly?

Comment: What does `$db_erg` contain?

Comment: The Problem ist, how to get the result for each entry?     while ($row = $db_erg->fetch_array())
    { ???

Comment: Maybe - what is the problem with iterating over the result?

Comment: You should start with the manual.

Comment: echo $row[0]; was the solution for my problem.

Comment: @Aneconomist mssql and mysql are two different animals. I can't see how that would be a duplicate of that.

Comment: @C2486 same thing applies here, as per my comment above ^

Answer (score 1):

```php
$sql = 'SELECT WEEK(date) AS week FROM table1 WHERE YEAR(date) = 2018';
```

For the WHERE clause, you might want to investigate whether avoiding the YEAR method provides performance advantages.

```sql
WHERE date BETWEEN CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AND CAST('2018-12-31' AS DATE);

WHERE date >= CAST('2018-01-01' AS DATE) AND date <= CAST('2018-12-31' AS DATE);
```

`$db_erg` in the above is the results (a [mysqi_result](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php) object), so you should be able to get them with a while loop.

```php
// check query succeeded
if ($db_erg) {

    while ($row = $db_erg->fetch_array())
    {
        // process the data
        echo $row[0]; // or $row['week'] if you used AS week
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I get the result of the query? $db_erg = mysqli_query($con, $sql); echo?

Comment: Added extra info

Comment: Thanks, But how do I build the syntax in the WHILE loop to get the two calendar weeks from the example?

Comment: Just `echo $row[0]`

Comment: Thanks, @vogomatix that was the solution ;)

Comment: Cool. Please accept and upvote answer if/when you can. I've also edited your question to clear up what you needed answering.